# extending definition of a function to make it continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have two functions on hand, namely
$$f(x) = x^3\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$$
and
$$f(x) = \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$$

I would like to know where are these functions discontinuous, and how do I extend the definitions to make them continuous?

I do think that the second equation will require the use of the following result: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x}x = 1$.

Comment: Are you asking for $\lim \limits_0(f)$?

Answer (score 1):

At $x=0$ they are discontinuous since the first function is not defined at $0$and the second is also not defined.

For the first function use sandwitch theorem $(-1 \le cosx \le 1$ for all $x)$

and for the second this trigonometric identity will help $1-cosx=2sin^2(x/2)$ and define function equal to limit value you get at zero.

Comment: At $0$ they are not disconinuous because they are not defined.

Comment: Thank you @ajotatxe. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first function, $x^3$ is continuous, $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous everywhere except at 0, where it isn't defined, and $\cos$ is continuous. Now we use the following facts:

1. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $c$ then $fg$ is continuous at $c$.
2. If $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$ and $g$ is continuous at $c$ then $f \circ g$ is continuous at $c$.

Consequently $x^3\cos\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous everywhere except at 0, where it isn't defined.

As one characteristic of a continuous function is that it respects limits, namely that $f(c) = \lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)$ for all $c$, we must have $f(0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$. You now need only find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$.

The second function can be analyzed similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Both functions are continuous in their domain, which is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

If you want to define a function $f^*$ defined and continuous in $\Bbb R$ which has the same values as $f$ in the domain of $f$ you must define

$$f^*(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
f(x)&\text{ if }x\neq 0\\
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)&\text{ if }x=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

Now, you must compute that limit. For the first funcion
$$|f(x)|=|x|^3|\cos x|\leq|x|^3\stackrel{x\to 0}{\to} 0$$
and for the second
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{2}=\frac12$$

It can also be possible that the limit does not exist (that includes the case of that the 'limit is infinity'). If it is the case, the continuous extension is impossible.

Comment: the l'hopital rule is not allowed in my module as we have not learnt the proof behind it ><